# Fitting entire image in circle

Tags: html, css, image

```css
.circle_border {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.Text{
font-size: 18px;
padding: 10px 0px 0px; 
line-height:normal;
}


.images1 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 125px;
    width: auto;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
}

.circle_border:hover .images1 {
   background: transparent;
 border: 4px solid #67508F;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: transparent !important;
 
  margin-top:4px;

 /*{Shadow}*/
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 0 #333;
 -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 0 #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px 0 #333, 0 1px 1px 0 #fff;
} 

.circle_border:hover .Text {
 cursor: pointer;
 color:#67508F !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_border">
<img src="doctor.png" class="images1 zoomIn" alt="Save icon"/>
<p class="Text">
Doctor</p>
</div>
```

I want to fit this below image in circle which is of width 125px. But my image is getting crop. How should i get the entire image in my circle. here is my image[image]

I have created one class circle_border for creating the circle and image class for adjusting the height and width of the image.

```
.circle_border {
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -ms-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.images1 {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 125px;
    width: auto;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 62.5px;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML code as well :)

Comment: can you create a snippet for this

Comment: You can put the image as background of your circle and use background-size: contain

Comment: it is necessary to keep width 125px?

Comment: I have tried to make snippet but i dun know how to add image in snippet. 125px is necessary because i want to use this as options for my questions.

Comment: Try It [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fg22tpz/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```css
div {width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;}

img{width: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 22px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6snp2.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
.circle_border img{
   display: block;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `border`, `border-radius` and size to your image-wrapper. The image itself should just take 100% width. This way you have all the control over the block styling via the wrapper.

see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5u87zg0/)